# Web accessibility - Label

Tags: html, accessibility, label

```
    <div class="searchWrap">
        <label for="SearchBox">Search Scirra</label>
        <input type="text" name="SearchBox" id="SearchBox" tabindex="1" />
        <div class="s searchIco"></div>
    </div>
```

- My labels style is display:none, is this OK?
- Also, are labels still used, and are they important?  It's the first time I've seen the HTML tag but am researching accessibility for my new site.

**Edit**

Quick question also, the primary reason for this of course is to help the less fortunate, but does this stuff also help for SEO, as a web crawler is also essentially blind?

Comment: @Pekka Because I don't want it on my website visually, it looks rubbish.

Comment: When you click on a LABEL, the corresponding form element gets focused. (In case you didn't know that)

Comment: Also, if you put the INPUT inside the LABEL, then you don't need the for attribute on the label to associate them.

Comment: @Sime thanks, no I didn't know that.  Am I misusing it in this case then?  I'm trying to just use it a describer for screen readers I don't want my regular visitors to see it as any text in that searchwrap detracts from the page style.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `label` element is still used, and I hope it stays that way (people with disabilities are especially thankful for them).

The clear semantic tie between the input element and the `label` allow a screen reader to clearly dictate to the user what information should be entered to which inputs.

As for `display: none` on it, I'm not sure if that will still be read. If not, you could try `text-indent: -9999px`.

[Fangs](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/fangs-screen-reader-emulator/) is a good screen reader emulator to test this out on. It requires FireFox.

Whilst on the topic of accessibility, you could turn that input into a HTML5 [`search` input](http://diveintohtml5.info/forms.html#type-search).

Browsers that support it will know semantically exactly what it is as it can't infer it from your `class`/`id`/`label`/etc.

#### Update

> I'm trying to just use it a describer for screen readers I don't want my regular visitors to see it as any text in that searchwrap detracts from the page style.

You could use the HTML5 `placeholder` attribute, this will display some text inside the element which describes what it does (search in this case). It is not widely supported, but there is JavaScript that emulates it (I wrote a [jQuery plugin](https://github.com/alexanderdickson/inputLabel) that does it).

One last thing, is I like to put `label { cursor: pointer }` in my CSS to help users know that it is clickable (very useful for checkboxes and radio boxes).

Comment: While understandably tempting, using `placeholder` attributes in place of `label` elements should probably be avoided from an accessibility standpoint. http://ux.stackexchange.com/a/28520

Answer (score 2):

`display: none;` must be used with caution - when elements are removed from the DOM in this way, assistive software cannot access that information until you specifically set the element to display again. For some assistive software, `visibility: hidden;` exhibits this same behaviour, i.e. that the hidden content is not read out by the software.

If you wish to hide content that is useful to screen readers, `text-indent:-999px;` or `position:absolute;left:-999px;` are known to be fairly safe, although I've heard there are some edge cases where the `position:absolute;` technique can cause problems. More recently, the [`clip` CSS property has been suggested as a solution](http://yaccessibilityblog.com/library/accessible-hiding-content.html).

Also, I wanted to note that implicit labelling by wrapping the `<input>` in the `<label>` has been [known to cause issues in some screen reader software](http://green-beast.com/blog/?p=254). Explicit labelling (using `for` and `id` attributes) is more robust and won't break if you ever decide to rearrange your HTML. If you're worried about backwards compatibility, IE 6 and below do not do the "click label to focus input" behaviour unless you use explicit labelling.

EDIT: I forgot to mention that it is valid to label a form input using a `title` attribute on the `<input>` element to replace the `<label>` element, which would avoid the need to hide the label at all. More info: [Title Attributes as Form Control Labels](http://www.accessibleculture.org/research/title-attributes-as-form-control-labels/).

Answer (score 0):

If you are hiding the content from `Average` visitors but want those with higher accessibility needs to be able to see it, you can make the lable display none on your standard css, and then use a `media` specific CSS to make it visible as needed.

[CSS: Media](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/media.html)

Comment: My research has found that `speech` and `aural` media types [enjoy very limited support](http://lab.dotjay.co.uk/notes/css/aural-speech/). Most assistive software works by accessing a browser's DOM (which usually means that CSS is interpreted by the browser and not the assistive software) or through "scraping" the screen, so the `screen` media type would dictate what is "visible" to the software.

Comment: @dotjay "CSS not being interpreted by the assistive software": That would seem to contradict the answer you gave to the question... Just confused, I honestly don't know very much about Assistive Software

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, Shad. Taking screen readers as an example, since they work on top of the browser, they essentially see what the browser renders. So, while screen readers don't parse CSS themselves, they _are_ subject to the CSS interpreted by the browser they are working with.